# Physics engine for game programming

Tags: physics-engine

I'm in the process of picking an open source physics engine for game programming with Direct3D 11. So far I have looked at Newton, Bullet Physics, and ODE.

Does anbody here have real-life experiences with one of those or any other engine that could help me making a decision?

Comment: You might get better answers asking this question on Game Development - http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've only looked and played with Tokamak, ODE, Bullet, and PhysX. Among these I found Tokamak the easiest but it was also the most limited and probably considered obsolete today. The second I found reasonably easy to use was Bullet. ODE was the hardest for me and took the longest time to get started. PhysX wasn't bad.

Answer (score 0):

Bullet is used in Blender, so it can't be that bad... But I don't have experience with any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Bullet is very easy to use, there is a detailed manual, many wrappers for things like OGRE and it's open source :) What more would you possibly need?

Answer (score 0):

ODE is old project and many projects that used ODE switched Bullet.
Newton and Bullet work differently. Can't say which is better.

I personally used Bullet and Nvidia PhysX.
PhysX is free in certain cases but not open source.

I have not used Newton because when I started my project Newton was close source and licensing  was unclear. They asked to contact them.

Any physics engine work well only in certain ranges.

Bullet physics is good because it is simple. 
It is based on collision detection and collision solver.
Both are very efficient for general use. 
Some parts of bullet physics could be replaced with alternatives.